# Syntax highlighting with bogado/file-line and slim-template/vim-slim (e.g. when doing `vim app/views/sessions/new.html.slim:20`)

Tags: vimrc, plugin

when I edit a slim file by line, e.g. `vim app/views/sessions/new.html.slim:20` I don't get the syntax highlighting :(, other types of files work fine (e.g. ruby files).

I use `slim-template/vim-slim` and `bogado/file-line`:

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set autoindent
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set nocompatible
set shell=/bin/bash
set viminfo='20,<1000
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]

filetype plugin indent on

syntax on

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'
Plugin 'bogado/file-line'
Plugin 'yuezk/vim-js'
Plugin 'maxmellon/vim-jsx-pretty'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails'
Plugin 'vim-crystal/vim-crystal'
Plugin 'slim-template/vim-slim'

call vundle#end()

fun! TrimWhitespace()
    let l:save = winsaveview()
    keeppatterns %s/\s\+$//e
    call winrestview(l:save)
endfun

autocmd BufWritePre * :call TrimWhitespace()

" Go to the last cursor location when a file is opened, unless this is a
" git commit (in which case it's annoying)
au BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &filetype != "gitcommit" |
        \ execute("normal `\"") |
    \ endif
```

Comment: Start with [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I found why, it's because the `syntax on` was before my plugins

Answer (score 2):

I needed to put `syntax on` after the imports of the plugins:

```
call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```